# JPA Specification<T> join query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Help me write the JPA request correctly.

There are two entities:

```
@Entity
class Box {

@Id
private long id;

@OneToMany
private List<Item> itemList;
}
```

```
@Entity
class Item {

@Id
private long id;

private String name;
}
```

The database contains records:

```
Box
id
1    
     Item
     id   name
L    1    aaa
L    2    aaa

Box
id
2    
     Item
     id   name
L    3    aaa
L    4    bbb

Box
id
3    
     Item
     id   name
L    5    bbb
L    6    bbb
```

I make a selection through the Specification interface

```
@Data
@Builder
class BoxFilter implements Specification<Box> {
private String itemName;

@Override
public Predicate securedPredicate(Root<Cargo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("itemList").get("name"), itemName));
    query.distinct(true);
return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
}
```

I make a request to the database like this:

```
BoxFilter boxFilter = BoxFilter.builder().itemName("aaa").build();

List<Box> boxList = boxRepo.findAll(boxFilter);
```

**Question**

How can I compose a request in BoxFilter so that the result is:

```
Box
id
1    
     Item
     id   name
L    1    aaa
L    2    aaa

Box
id
2    
     Item
     id   name
L    3    aaa
```

I can't do it myself.
PS. I do not understand how the check to defeat the post on this site. Doesn't let you post the question and that's it ...

Answer (score 0):

The way you implemented the `Specification` you need to override the following method.

```java
@Nullable
    Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder);
```

Rename your function name `securePredicate` to `toPredicate` will do the trick.